# How to get all distinct combinations of pairs in C# / LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Tuple of pairs with the same type e.g.: [1,1][1,2][2,1][2,1]

I need to calculate the distinct combinations: [1,1][1,2]

```
public void DistinctPairsTest()
{
    IList<Tuple<int, int>> pairs = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
    pairs.Add(Tuple.Create(1, 1));
    pairs.Add(Tuple.Create(1, 2));
    pairs.Add(Tuple.Create(2, 1));
    pairs.Add(Tuple.Create(2, 1));

    IList<Tuple<int, int>> distinctPairs = GetDistinctPairs(pairs);

    Assert.AreEqual(2, distinctPairs.Count);
}

private IList<Tuple<T, T>> GetDistinctPairs<T>(IList<Tuple<T, T>> pairs)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

How would you implement the generic GetDistinctPairs(pairs) ?

Solution:

as Heinzi and Dennis_E suggested, I implemented a generic IEqualityComparer. Improvements are welcome :-)

```
public class CombinationEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<Tuple<T, T>>
{
    public bool Equals(Tuple<T, T> x, Tuple<T, T> y)
    {
        bool equals = new HashSet<T>(new[] { x.Item1, x.Item2 }).SetEquals(new[] { y.Item1, y.Item2 });
        return equals;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Tuple<T, T> obj)
    {
        return obj.Item1.GetHashCode() + obj.Item2.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could make Equals shorter: return (Equals(x.Item1, y.Item1) && Equals(x.Item2, y.Item2)) || (Equals(x.Item1, y.Item2) && Equals(x.Item2, y.Item1)). I'm not an expert on implementing GetHashCode(), but people often use prime numbers to multiply on of the numbers with, otherwise [a,b] will always give the same hashcode as [b,a]. So, something like: return obj.Item1.GetHashCode() * 31 + obj.Item2.GetHashCode();

Comment: @Dennis_E: This is by design: In this case, [a, b] *should* give the same hash code as [b, a], since `Equals([a, b], [b, a])` returns true. The documentation of [IEqualityComparer<T>.GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132155(v=vs.110).aspx) says: "*Implementations are required to ensure that if the Equals method returns true for two objects x and y, then the value returned by the GetHashCode method for x must equal the value returned for y.*"

Comment: Of course! (slaps forehead)

Comment: An even shorter implementation would be `return new HashSet<T>(new[] {x.Item1, x.Item2}).SetEquals(new[] {y.Item1, y.Item2});` However, that might be more appropriate for code golf...

Comment: Nice! I updated the solution

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is an [`Enumerable.Distinct` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049(v=vs.110).aspx) which allows you to specify an [`IEqualityComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx).

Provide a custom `IEqualityComparer<Tuple<T, T>>` that considers [1, 2] and [2, 1] to be equal.

The implementation should be trivial and is left as an exercise to the reader. :-)

Answer (score 5):

You could write a class that implements `IEqualityComparer<Tuple<int, int>>` and use that in a call to Distinct():

```
pairs.Distinct(new YourComparerClass());
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately @Heinzi was a bit more accurate (although it was almost the exact same answer)

Comment: Okidoki. We answered at exactly the same time. (happens a lot)